# Skip first column when adding new row for showing sum of grouped by DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add a row to the bottom of a grouped by data frame in Pandas, using following code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('manufacturers.csv')
gkk = df.groupby(['Country'])['Country'].count().reset_index(name='byCountry')
gkk.loc['Total by Country']= gkk['byCountry'].sum()
print(gkk)
```

the output is looks like
[image]

but I do not want to display the total number under the Country column. Instead I want to skip the first column and output it like:

[image]

How can I utilize this code `gkk.loc['Total by Country']= gkk['byCountry'].sum()` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `reset_index`, turning your Series into a DataFrame.

One option is to do this step only after you added the wanted row:

```
gkk = df.groupby(['Country'])['Country'].count()
gkk.loc['Total by Country'] = gkk.sum()

gkk = gkk.reset_index(name='byCountry')
```

Or keep the `reset_index` and assign with a dictionary:

```
gkk = df.groupby(['Country'])['Country'].count().reset_index(name='byCountry')
gkk.loc[''] = {'County': 'Total by Country',
               'byCountry': gkk['byCountry'].sum()}
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, but `gkk = gkk.reset_index(name='byCountry')` causing an error `TypeError: DataFrame.reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: @Behseini can you edit your question to add your input in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464)?